# Is "for better clarity" a correct expression?

Tags: expressions

Consider the following sentence:

> For better clarity, we will now explain in detail how this works.

Is "for better clarity" correct as an expression? [Googling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22for+better+clarity%22&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=tObOWJS3LIzRgAanqpvQCQ) for it gives a number of results but none from a "grammatically safe" source.

If grammatically correct, is it commonly used? Does it sound natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For clarity* would be the better construction. [This Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20clarity%2Cfor%20better%20clarity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20clarity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20better%20clarity%3B%2Cc0) of *for clarity* vs *for better clarity* shows the clear preference for the former, giving this:

> *For clarity*, we will now explain in detail how this works.

Comment: It's common also to hear *for greater clarity".

Comment: [More common than *for better clarity*, I suppose...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+clarity%2Cfor+better+clarity%2Cfor+greater+clarity&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20clarity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20better%20clarity%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20greater%20clarity%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: Yes, it's much more common.